# Changing image size to full size in Gutenberg's block gallery

Tags: plugins, gallery, block-editor

I'm using Wordpress 5.0 and I love it so far. The only problem I have with Gutenberg editor is that its "block gallery" doesn't work so well. I have some 4K screenshots in block gallery, but it looks like that Gutenberg displays those images in "large" size instead of full size in lightbox. Does anyone have an idea how can I modify it?

Here's my site - https://www.gameron.pl/recenzje/red-dead-redemption-2/ - you can check the block gallery yourself.

I'm desperate for help,
Kacper